# How can I check whether the solution $y=1$ to the integral equation $1=\int_a^b y^{1 / x} f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x\,, $ is unique?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following equation for $y$:
$$ 1 = \int_a^b y^{1 / x} f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x\,, $$
where $f(x)$ is a density function with support over the interval $[a,b]$, so that $\int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = 1$. Clearly, $y=1$ is a solution, but how can I check whether the solution $y=1$ is unique?

For context, in my application I assume that $f(x)$ is the density function for the Pareto distribution.

Comment: $g(y) := \int_a^b\, y^{1/x}\,f(x)\, dx$ is positive and so is its first derivative.

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$, or a constant real number?

Comment: $y$ is a constant real number.

Comment: @Aruralreader, am I right to understand from your comment that $g^{\prime}(y) > 0$ is sufficient for uniqueness? I suppose it would be, need to think more about that, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: If $y_1 < y_2$, then $y_1^{1/x} < y_2^{1/x}$ for any positive $x$. What does that tell you about $\int_a^b y_1^{1/x}f(x)dx$ and $\int_a^b y_2^{1/x}f(x)dx$?

Comment: Thank you @eyeballfrog, that makes it even more clear!